# Fetch Email Signature using googleAPI

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I am using googleAPI and Nodejs to fetch mails in details using oauth2.0. But I am not getting email's signature with image attached format. What is API to fetch incoming email with signature as image attached format?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by signature as an image? How is the signature added to the email? Also, Please provide a sample of your code where you fetch the email.

Comment: We can set image/photo as an signature of email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A signature as an image is incorporated by Gmail not as an attachment or inline image, but rather as a download link assigned to `img src` within the text/html of your message body.

Here a snippet of the response you obtain if you log the body of the message retrieved in raw format (the domain name and file ID replaced with XXX for privacy reasons):

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr"><br clear=3D"all"><div><div dir=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail_sig=
nature" data-smartmail=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><img src=3D"htt=
ps://drive.google.com/a/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/uc?id=3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
sYV-&amp;export=3Ddownload"><br></div></div></div></div>
```

Keep in mind that the URL is quoted-printable encoded. You need to remove the soft line breaks `=` and replace `=3D` by `=` to obtain the correct URL - something like

```
https://drive.google.com/a/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/uc?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXsYV-&amp;export=download
```

This link you can either open in your browser or access it programmatically by getting the body part of your message (filtering for `Content-Type: text/html`)  and extracting the link e.g. with a Regex expression.

Comment: Thank you so much for a answer.I have one question that, from that link,we can download the image ?

Comment: Yes, you will see it yourself if you just paste the link into your browser address bar - just make sure that you convert it from quoted printable to original.

Comment: I got solution.Thank you very much